# How to find a position in a integer

Tags: vb.net

If I had a integer that was, for example 11110011. How would I find out what number was in each position so I could use them calculate something. Thanks

Comment: Are those binary, or just a decimal?

Answer (score 1):

cast it to String and then use method of string to find the int at a particular position.

Comment: I do not think that's a good solution, first of all because you didn't explain to him how to do it or gave him any way to learn - and he seems fairly new, and second, because the method seems just wrong in my eyes - he asked for a way to work with numbers and digit and you're using an uneccessary cast.

Comment: he is new he should explore how to do things if i will give him the full solution it will be of no help. he never mentioned anything about casting. there is alot of ways of doing one thing.it is not about your opinion it about doing it fast and easy.thanks

Comment: In which case, I'd expect at least a link to a place where he can learn this.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to [read a bit about operators if you wish.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx)
Anyhow i'd use a loop of `Mod 10` and divide by 10 each iteration.

Pseudo code:

```
Given number
While number is not zero
    Get the mod 10 of the number
    ... Do what you need to do with it - that's the digit
    Divide by 10.
    Repeat.
Done.
```

for example:

```
Dim yourNumber As Integer = 12930 // for example.
While index >0
Dim digit As Integer = yourNumber Mod 10
Debug.Write(digit.ToString & " ")
index /= 1
End While
```

Will write all the digits, seperated by a space:

```
output: 1 2 3 9 0
```